# Two foreign key referencing to same primary key being used as a composite key[ERD]

Tags: sql, erd

I want to draw an ERD, showing the relationship between two tables. Below are their sql queries.

```
CREATE TABLLE USERS(userid INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCAHR(20));

CREATE TABLE RATING(userid INT REFERENCES USERS(userid), userid2 INT REFERENCES USERS(userid), number int, PRIMARY KEY(userid, userid2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the screen shot of your ER Diagram:

[image: ER Digram]

Some more information/tips:

I am not sure, which RDMS you are using, but if you have access to SQL Server Management studio an ER diagram can be created quickly by below steps:

1. Go to Sql Server Management Studio >
2. Object Explorer >
3. Databases >
4. Choose and expand your Database.
5. Under your database right click on "Database Diagrams" and select "New
6. Database Diagram".
7. It will a open a new window. ...
8. Select the tables "Users" and "Rating" Click add (1 time for each table). Then click close
9. Wait for it to complete.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! .. I actually wanted a diagram like this one(just an example):  https://lbsitbytes2010.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/simple-er-diagram-roll-no9/      Is it possible?